# Why does `__builtins__` not contain itself?

Tags: python, python-builtins

The following code seems like a good way to get an overview of the builtin objects in Python.

```py
dunder = []  # 8

lower_fun = []  # 41
lower_type = []  # 26
lower_sitebuiltins = []  # 6

upper_exception = []  # 50
upper_warning = []  # 11
upper_other = []  # 10


for name, obj in vars(__builtins__).items():
    first_char = name[0]
    if first_char == '_':
        dunder.append(name)
    else:
        if first_char.islower():
            t = str(type(obj))
            if t == "<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>":
                lower_fun.append(name)
            elif t == "<class 'type'>":
                lower_type.append(name)
            elif '_sitebuiltins' in t:
                lower_sitebuiltins.append(name)
            else:
                assert False  # does not happen
        else:
            if 'Error' in name or 'Exception' in name:
                upper_exception.append(name)
            elif 'Warning' in name:
                upper_warning.append(name)
            else:
                upper_other.append(name)
```

I would have expected `__builtins__` to appear in `dunder`. But it is not there.

```py
dunder == [
    '__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__',
    '__spec__', '__build_class__', '__import__', '__debug__'
]
```

Apparently I do not understand, what "built in" means.
So what are the 152 entries of `vars(__builtins__)`?
And what (like `__builtins__`) is missing?

---

**Edit:** `builtins` and `sys` are also not in these lists.

The 152 entries came from running this code from a Python file.
In a console `dir(__builtins__)` looks completely different, and has only 41 entries.
`vars(__builtins__)` causes a TypeError in the console.

Initially the code used `dir(__builtins__)`. Following the advice in a comment, it was rewritten using `vars(__builtins__)`. The result is essentially the same, but the lists have a different order.

Comment: `__builtins__` is just the module for the built-in *namespace*, this will be accessible from anywhere in Python (it sits above `globals()`, which are *module scoped*). So all the names that come with the runtime, e.g. `list`, `StopIterationError`, basically anything that won't throw a `NameError` if you run an empty python module, check out `print(__builtins__.__doc__)`

Comment: `t = str(eval(f'type({name})'))` don't do this. You really shouldn't use `dir` to begin with. Use `vars(__builtins__)` which gives you a dict, so you can use `for name, obj in vars(__builtins__).items(): ... ` then just `type(obj)`

Comment: `__builtins__` is a CPython-specific trick. It's not inside itself to prevent infinite recursion. It does not have to follow "typical" rules, and is not always defined - as you might have noticed, `import builtins; print(builtins.__builtins__)` fails with `AttributeError`. I don't know about any other module where this happens and strongly believe that `builtins` is the only exception, exactly to avoid self-reference.

Comment: @STerliakov yep, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html): "As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python." I don't think it would require infinite recursion, just a circular reference, but it happens not to do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep, that should've been reference, not recursion, I even corrected myself in the last sentence!:)

Comment: I think `builtins.__builtins__` is omitted simply because it's not needed, not to avoid a cyclic reference. (See `types.FunctionType.__call__.__call__.__call__....`)

Comment: Any ideas why `sys` is also not in `vars(__builtins__)`?

Comment: @Watchduck why would `sys` be in `vars(__builtins__)`? It isn't part of the built-in namespace. It is its own module, that you typically import. If you do `print(sys)` in an empty module and run that it would raise a `NameError`

Comment: That is indeed true, when I run this code in a file. In the console I just have `sys`. (It identifies itself as `<module 'sys' (built-in)>`.) Yet, `sys in dir(__builtins__)` is false in the console. Anyway, `dir(__builtins__)` in the console seems to be quite different from what my question is about. So my sub-question about `sys` does not really matter.